# Make distutils look for numpy header files in the correct place

Tags: python, numpy, distutils, cython

In my installation, numpy's `arrayobject.h` is located at `…/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h`.  I wrote a trivial Cython script that uses numpy:

```
cimport numpy as np

def say_hello_to(name):
    print("Hello %s!" % name)
```

I also have the following distutils `setup.py` (copied from the [Cython user guide](http://docs.cython.org/src/quickstart/build.html)):

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"])]

setup(
  name = 'Hello world app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

When I try to build with `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`, Cython tries to do the following:

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-long-double -no-cpp-precomp -mno-fused-madd \
-fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DMACOSX \
-I/usr/include/ffi -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -pipe \
-I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/include/python2.5 \
-c hello.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.5-i386-2.5/hello.o
```

Predictably, this fails to find `arrayobject.h`.  How can I make distutils use the correct location of numpy include files (without making the user define $CFLAGS)?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use `numpy.get_include()`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy as np                           # <---- New line

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"],
                                  include_dirs=[get_numpy_include()])]   # <---- New argument

setup(
  name = 'Hello world app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},       
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

Comment: I have the same problem when using the `%%cython` magic in an ipython notebook.. I wonder if there is an easy fix for that as well

Comment: For anyone looking at this as an example for non-`numpy` related work, the definition of `numpy.get_include` is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/56678fe56dce97871bb49febf0b2c0206541eada/numpy/lib/utils.py#L18).

Comment: im not sure if i implemented it correctly but it seems like this renders `setup.py` useless for remote installations. You get an error ` ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

Comment: will try to make it work with pipenv, works with `pip install` thanks

Comment: pip 19 and above breaks all of this again due to enforcement of PEP517/518

Comment: this works, but do not work in releasing it to pypi since I do not have numpy package installed!

Comment: Should `get_numpy_include()` not be `np.get_include()`?

Comment: distutils is deprecated

Answer (score 32):

The answer given by @vebjorn-ljosa is correct, but it causes problems when used in conjunction with `install_requires=['numpy']`. In this situation, your setup.py needs to import numpy, which will cause an error if you try to `pip install` your project without running `pip install numpy` first.

If your project depends on numpy, and you want numpy to be installed automatically as a dependency, you need to set include_dirs only when your extensions are actually being built. You can do this by subclassing `build_ext`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

class CustomBuildExtCommand(build_ext):
    """build_ext command for use when numpy headers are needed."""
    def run(self):

        # Import numpy here, only when headers are needed
        import numpy

        # Add numpy headers to include_dirs
        self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())

        # Call original build_ext command
        build_ext.run(self)

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"])]

setup(
  name = 'Hello world app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': CustomBuildExtCommand},
  install_requires=['numpy'],
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

And you can use a similar trick to add cython as an automatically installed dependency:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension

try:
    from Cython.setuptools import build_ext
except:
    # If we couldn't import Cython, use the normal setuptools
    # and look for a pre-compiled .c file instead of a .pyx file
    from setuptools.command.build_ext import build_ext
    ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.c"])]
else:
    # If we successfully imported Cython, look for a .pyx file
    ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"])]

class CustomBuildExtCommand(build_ext):
    """build_ext command for use when numpy headers are needed."""
    def run(self):

        # Import numpy here, only when headers are needed
        import numpy

        # Add numpy headers to include_dirs
        self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())

        # Call original build_ext command
        build_ext.run(self)

setup(
  name = 'Hello world app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': CustomBuildExtCommand},
  install_requires=['cython', 'numpy'],
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

Note: these approaches only work with `pip install .`. They won't work for `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop` as in these commands cause dependencies to be installed after your project, rather than before.

Comment: distutils is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

For anyone not using Cython,  a slight modification of R_Beagrie's solution without that dependency is if you simply import build_ext from distutils.command.build_ext instead of Cython.

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from distutils.command.build_ext import build_ext

class CustomBuildExtCommand(build_ext):
    """build_ext command for use when numpy headers are needed."""
    def run(self):

        # Import numpy here, only when headers are needed
        import numpy

        # Add numpy headers to include_dirs
        self.include_dirs.append(numpy.get_include())

        # Call original build_ext command
        build_ext.run(self)

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.c"])]

setup(
  name = 'Hello world app',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': CustomBuildExtCommand},
  install_requires=['numpy'],
  ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

Comment: distutils is deprecated