# Missing numpy/arrayobject.h while compiling .pyx file

Tags: python, macos, numpy

Installed canopy from enthought.  While building my `.pyx` file, I get this error (followed by more)

Do I need to easy_install additional packages to get the "development" version so I get the `.h` files?

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -c tsBinner.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/tsBinner.o
tsBinner.c:314:31: error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
tsBinner.c:315:31: error: numpy/ufuncobject.h: No such file or directory
```

## More Context

This compiles and runs under several Linux installations, but does not work with my recently-installed Canopy distribution python

here is the content of setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [Extension("tsBinner",["tsBinner.pyx"])]

setup(
  name ='time stamp binner',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules 
)
```

Here is the content of tsBinner.py

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

#cimport cython
#@cython.boundscheck(False)
def tsBinner(np.ndarray[np.uint64_t, ndim=1] tstamps, \
    np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] bins):
    """
    bin the values of the tstamps array into the bins array.

    tstamps array is of type np.uint64

    bins array is of type int
    """
    cdef int nTStamps = tstamps.shape[0]
    cdef int iTStamp
    for iTStamp in range(nTStamps):
        bins[tstamps[iTStamp]] += 1
    return
```

Here are the versions of python and gcc

```
mac-119562:cosmic stoughto$ which python
/Users/stoughto/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/User/bin/python
mac-119562:cosmic stoughto$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
mac-119562:cosmic stoughto$ gcc --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build     2336.11.00)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

mac-119562:cosmic stoughto$ python --version
Python 2.7.3 --  64-bit
```

Running on a MacBook Pro Mac OS X Version 10.7.5

Comment: Some more context would be nice.

Comment: I had the same problem, you have to include also `-I.../site-packages/numpy/core/include` in your gcc command...

Comment: You can try to import from `numpy.distutils.core` instead of `distutils.core`, not sure if it will make any difference.

Comment: Jaime, sorry changing the import did not work.

Comment: Saullo, thanks, that helps.  I did it by setting the environment variable CPATH to /Users/.../site-packages/numpy/core before running the command "python setup.py buils_ext --inplace" command.  Is there a way to include logic (in setup.py?) to make this more portable?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14657375/cython-fatal-error-numpy-arrayobject-h-no-such-file-or-directory Did you try using the include_dirs argument as suggested there?

Comment: @user2824549 the portable solution I use here is to create a shell script that includes all the `-I...` when calling `gcc` or `cython`. [Here is an example of such script for Windows...](https://gist.github.com/saullocastro/6741739)

Comment: @user2824549 I think you can set the environment variable `INCLUDE` and `LIB` to tell the compiler where to look for headers and libraries, respectively...

Answer (score 5):

This is a fairly old question, but it is a frequent problem and the other answers are very bad. Hard-wiring numpy's include directory completely breaks virtual environments and would make the package very hard to distribute and install automatically. The correct way to solve this is using `numpy.get_include()` to obtain the directory associated with the currently loaded numpy version. This is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2379912) answer to a similar problem. The `setup.py` would be like this:

```
import numpy
setup(
  name ='time stamp binner',
  cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
  ext_modules = ext_modules,
  include_dirs = [numpy.get_include()] #Include directory not hard-wired
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the compiler to include the directory where your header files reside using the following parameter in your setup.py:

```
ext_modules = [Extension("tsBinner",["tsBinner.pyx"],
              include_dirs = ["/full/path/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/"])];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem found in all Canopy distributions. The answer below is for a Mac. It should be fairly obvious what to do in Linux and Windows; the folders are just slightly different.

---

After making the .c file, the setup.py file automatically runs the following for you

```
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -arch x86_64 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch x86_64 -I/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7 -c MyCythonCode.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-x86_64-2.7/MyCythonCode.o
```

Then you get the errors about the missing .h files: `arrayobject.h` and `ufuncobject.h`

Looking at the code above, in particular the `-I` option, the problem lies in that gcc is looking for these files in:

```
/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/include/python2.7
```

Type the following into a terminal window, to find where these files are:

```
find /Applications/ -name "ufuncobject.h"
```

For the Canopy installation on my Mac, they appeared in a couple of place. The location I'm interested in is the folder of the latest Canopy update (1.1.0.1371 for me). So the files ere located, for me, here:

```
/Applications//Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ufuncobject.h
```

Note that the error messages ask for two files within a folder called `numpy`. If you just copy the two files in question, then you'll hit more errors. Copy the whole of the `numpy` folder, in this case the folder located in (one folder up from before):

```
/Applications//Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/
```

Paste this folder into the folder the compiler is looking in (i.e. the one listed as the `-I` option above). In my case, this is:

```
/Applications//Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.1.0.1371.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/
```

Now try running the setup file again. It should be okay.

I have always found this to be an issue with Enthought distributions. As great as EPD was and Canopy is, it's a real pain that this has to be manually fixed each time.

Hope this helps.