# Cython+NumPy - compiler not using numpy.pyd

Tags: python, gcc, numpy, cython

I have a code that uses numpy and I want to compile it using Cython. I added the cimport directive:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
```

I am on Windows 7, compiling using distutils with gcc (MinGW) as the compiler. It yields an error when I try to compile it. This is the error:

```
ssepMC.c:346:31: fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
 #include "numpy/arrayobject.h"
                               ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I believe this error occurs because the compiler is trying to compile the numpy package. But this is an unnecessary step because a compiled version of numpy exists in Cython under

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Includes\numpy\numpy.pxd
```

So the question is: How do I make the compiler use the compiled version of numpy?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379898/make-distutils-look-for-numpy-header-files-in-the-correct-place).

Comment: Thanks @IanH, this seems to solve it. However if there's a way to not compile numpy, but use the precompiled version, it would be cool

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with NumPy's internals to say which bits of NumPy this is re-compiling. I doubt it will be an issue, but I could be wrong. Really though, in practice, if you don't want to deal with this dependency, [memory views](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) are the easiest route to take.

Comment: I'll have a look at it. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned elsewhere, you need to point `gcc` to `numpy/arrayobject.h` which you can do by setting `include_dirs` to `[np.get_include()]`.

Note - this is not 'recompiling' numpy, this is using the directives in the numpy arrayheader file to instruct `gcc` how to compile your code.

```
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy as np

ext_modules = [Extension("hello", ["hello.pyx"], include_dirs=[np.get_include()])]

setup(
  ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
)
```