# fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, c++, numpy, g++

I am limited on what I can share as this is part of a huge stack of code that I am porting from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.

It should be trivial, but somehow I am struggling with this. It doesn't find `numpy/arrayobject.h` that I am referencing in my source file with `#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>`

I will try to share as much as I can, see if someone can guide me through a resolution.

### Ubuntu

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

### make

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

### g++

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
```

upgraded to

```
# g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.1-2ubuntu1~16.04) 5.4.1 20160904
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

### python

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

### Some environment variables

```
PYTHON       /usr/bin/python2.7
ARCH         x86_64
OS           Linux
VERSION      4.4.071generic
PLATFORM     linux2
HOSTNAME     deploy
USER         myUser
WUSS_BUILD   NO
CCVER        gcc
PYLIBDIR     build.x86_64-linux2
LIBDIR       build.x86_64-linux2
BINDIR       build.x86_64-linux2
ODIR         build.x86_64-linux2-gcc
STATICLIBDIR build-static.x86_64-linux2
```

#### Error

The `make` command leads to

```
+++ Compile mycore/boost_numpy.cc to build.x86_64-linux2-gcc
anycore/boost_numpy.cc:2:31: fatal error: numpy/arrayobject.h: No such file or directory
```

#### My source file

```
user@deploy:~/my-linux$ vim mycore/boost_numpy.cc

#include "anycore/boost_python_headers.h"
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>           <====== DECLARATION
#include <numpy/ufuncobject.h>        
#include "mycore/boost_numpy.h"
#include "mycore/numerical.h"
#include "mycore/vec3.h"

using namespace boost::python;

PyObject *
read_numeric_file_ficii(FILE *fp, int ncols, char arrtype, int headlines, int taillines)
{
  if (!(arrtype=='d' || arrtype=='f' || arrtype=='i')) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Unknown array type for read_numeric_file");
    return NULL;
  }
...FILTERED...
```

### Declaration file `numpy/arrayobject.h` on disk

```
root@deploy:/home#  find / -name arrayobject.h
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h
```

Please let me know how I can improve the question. Directions or pointers are most welcome

## UPDATE

```
$ ls -l /usr/include/numpy
ls: cannot access '/usr/include/numpy': No such file or directory
```

## RESOLVED WITH

```
sudo ln -s  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy /usr/include/numpy
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379898/make-distutils-look-for-numpy-header-files-in-the-correct-place

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I have experienced the same behavior on a partly broken Debian installation.

I fixed the error by reestablishing a symbolic link

`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy /usr/include/numpy`

Comment: Having similar issue on Alpine Linux with Python 3.7.  There isn't an `include` folder inside `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/`, any pointers?

Comment: Install the dev package for python

Comment: for manjaro the following helped `sudo ln -s /usr/lib64/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ /usr/include/numpy`

Answer (score 11):

How did you install numpy?

If you install `python-numpy` correctly, e.g. by `sudo apt-get install python-numpy`, you will have `/usr/include/numpy` linked to the correct path:

```
$ ls -l /usr/include/numpy
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 55 Sep 17  2014 /usr/include/numpy -> ../lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy
```

It looks like you may build your numpy manually, then you can manually create a soft link accordingly.

Comment: This solution works in my case because I installed numpy using conda.