# Cython can't access numpy header files

Tags: numpy, anaconda, cython

```
cimport numpy as np
import functools

cpdef _get_eligible_chs_bitmap(np.ndarray[np.npy_bool, ndim=3] grid, tuple cell):
    """Find eligible chs by bitwise ORing the allocation maps of neighbors"""
    cdef int r, c
    r, c = cell
    cdef list neighs = neighbors(2, r, c, separate=True, include_self=True)
    cdef np.ndarray[np.int64_t, ndim=1] alloc_map = np.bitwise_or.reduce(grid[neighs])
    return alloc_map

def hex_distance(cell_a, cell_b):
    r1, c1 = cell_a
    r2, c2 = cell_b
    return (abs(r1 - r2) + abs(r1 + c1 - r2 - c2) + abs(c1 - c2)) / 2


@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def neighbors(dist, row, col, separate=False, include_self=False, rows=7, cols=7):
    """
    Returns a list with indices of neighbors with a distance of 'dist' or less
    from the cell at (row, col)

    If 'separate' is True, return ([r1, r2, ...], [c1, c2, ...]),
    else return [(r1, c1), (r2, c2), ...]
    """
    if separate:
        rs = []
        cs = []
    else:
        idxs = []
    for r2 in range(rows):
        for c2 in range(cols):
            if (include_self or (row, col) != (r2, c2)) \
                and hex_distance((row, col), (r2, c2)) <= dist:
                if separate:
                    rs.append(r2)
                    cs.append(c2)
                else:
                    idxs.append((r2, c2))
    if separate:
        return (rs, cs)
    return idxs
```

The call to the numpy's bitwise_or throws an error in the first function:

> cimported module has no attribute 'bitwise_or'

This problem seems similar to  ([Make distutils look for numpy header files in the correct place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379898/make-distutils-look-for-numpy-header-files-in-the-correct-place)), but I've tried both answers and they do not work.

Numpy and Cython both installed through Anaconda with Python 3.6.
The numpy header file is located at:
`/home/myname/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h`

## Edit:

Adding `import numpy as np` fixes the error when running cython, but introduces the following error when import the compiled file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ctest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import gridfuncs
  File "gridfuncs.pyx", line 2, in init dca.gridfuncs
    import numpy as np
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 951, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 894, in _find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1157, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1129, in _get_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1271, in find_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 96, in _path_isfile
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 88, in _path_is_mode_type
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The setup is just a compiled cython file with numpy imports and a python file import it.
ctest.py:

```
import gridfuncs
```

gridfuncs.pyx:

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
```

Compiled as such:

```
gcc -shared -pthread -fPIC -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -I/usr/include/python3.6m -I/home/torstein/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/ -o gridfuncs.so gridfuncs.c
```

Comment: try adding `import numpy as np` in addition to `cimport`

Comment: That worked, can I be sure it's 'using the right one'?

Comment: @ead Error does not appear when running cython, but I get complaints about maximum recursion depth exceeded on the `import numpy as np` line.

Comment: Could provide a minimal example and back trace of the error?

Comment: @ead yes, have updated the post

Comment: The minimum example just consists of importing the compiled cython file with the double numpy imports. All the other code can be removed and the error is still there.

Comment: No error here. Please consider: 1. Fix the mix of `/usr/...` and anaconda include paths. 2. Check that `gcc` is the proper compiler for building extensions with anaconda.

Comment: I would also say that something is wrong with your python-installation (no pythonpath set or similar).

Comment: It looks like it's picking up a "`dca`" somewhere in the module name (i.e. Cython has decided that your module is a submodule of something else). It's a guess but I think that might be relevant. No ideas for fixing it though...